# Prove that the elements of the group satisfy following equality

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Question: Let G denote a group generated by the transformation $S = -1/{\gamma}$ and $T^2$, where $T(\gamma)=\gamma +1$ . Now if matrix $ \begin{pmatrix}
a & b  \\ 
 c & d   \\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$ $\in G $ , then show that $a\equiv d \pmod 2$  and $b\equiv c \pmod 2$.

Any element of $T^{2k}$ will be given by $ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2k  \\ 
 0 & 1   \\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$ but I am not able to represent general element of $S^{k}$ by this as

$S= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 
 1 & 0   \\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$.

$S^{2}= \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0  \\ 
  0& -1   \\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$

$ S^{3}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\ 
 -1 & 0   \\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$

$S^4=S$.

So, I am not able to find an expression similar to expression of $T^{2k}$ which will be used for multiplying both and then to find a,b,c,d.

Can you please tell how should I find them. Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Since any element of $G$ has a form of $S^{a}T^{2b}S^{c}T^{2d}\cdots$, it is enough to show that the condition holds for $Sg$ and $T^{2}g$ if it holds for $g$, which shouldn't be hard. Since the identity matrix satisfies the condition, we can complete the proof by using induction.

---

If $g = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ satisfies $a \equiv d$ and $b \equiv c$, then $Sg = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} -c & -d \\ a & b \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ satisfies $-c \equiv c \equiv b$ and $-d \equiv d \equiv a$. Also, we have $T^{2}g = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a + 2c & b + 2d \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ and $a + 2c \equiv a \equiv d$ and $b + 2d \equiv b \equiv c$.

Comment: @Tim I don't think that we need to show the opposite. Why do you think that it is necesasry?

Comment: Ya, I am deleting my previous comment. I have no reason to beleive that if condition holds for G then It holds for Sg and $T^2 g$ ? Can you please Explain the reason ing behind it?

Comment: @Tim I added details.